# LibreOffice BASIC function - Copy if over a value to a new sheet

Tags: macros, copy, libreoffice, basic

I'm trying to create a simple function on a LibreOffice Calc sheet.

I have a table of information where cells A1:K2 has headings (the cells in Row 2 are merged)

all the information runs from A3:K176
The sheet has various functions running on it already, all I need is one more function.
At first I wanted it to automate when i open, but then i thought running the BASIC macro off of a button might be better, so i can edit and then just hit the button once I'm done.

I have the button linked up to run the macro already, but now im stuck... I have tried many ways of writing the code, but it seems that i am just too green to figure it out.
the last time i ran Excel advanced functions i was in high school.

ok, enough talking... 
All I need the macro to do is once I hit the button, I need it to check column K and any value > 1 it needs to take that whole row and copy it then  go to a target sheet, clear any data on the target sheet. then copy that set of rows to the next open row in the target sheet. possibly even exporting the result to a .txt file as a bonus.

this is a start...

in future I would like to add another button that will do the same function to a array lower down and put that into a different sheet.

```vb
Option Compatible
Sub SWD_AwakeningsTrade
    Dim i, LastRow
    LastRow = Sheets("Card_List").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Awakenings For trade").range("A2:I500").clearContents
    For i=2 to LastRow
        If Sheets("Card_List").Cells(i,"K").Value = "(>1)" Then
            Sheets("Card_List").Cells(i, "K").EntireRow.Copy
            Destination:=Sheets("Awakenings For trade").Range("A" & Rows.Count.end(xlUp)
        End if
    next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You've given a reasonably clear description of the task.  Now post the code you have tried so far, and describe the problems encountered along with any error messages.  Also post links to documentation or examples that you used.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: I have tried many different ways to do this, but i think the fault is on my lack of knowledge.

I Tried a few VBA methods, but i think my fault lies in the fact that this is LibreOffice Basic and all the ones I have been trying are for Excel.

I dont know what the correct Syntax or objects are for LO Basic.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-QFjJoRGCtU
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qGZQIl9JJk4
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kxvxPn5PnOk

Comment: Correct, Excel VBA is very different.  Please search for documentation and examples for LO Basic, such as http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php.

Comment: Option Compatible

Sub SWD_AwakeningsTrade



Dim i, LastRow

LastRow = Sheets("Card_List").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Awakenings For trade").range("A2:I500").clearContents
For i=2 to LastRow
If Sheets("Card_List").Cells(i,"K").Value = "(>1)" Then
Sheets("Card_List").Cells(i, "K").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Awakenings For trade").Range("A" & Rows.Count.end(xlUp)
End if
next i


End Sub

Comment: The code you posted looks like VBA, not LO Basic.  I do **not** recommend `Option Compatible`, because VBA and LO Basic are not very compatible even if you use that option, and it makes the code confusing.  Did you look at any LO Basic documentation or examples, starting from the link I suggested?  Also, does the code you posted work, and if not, what problems were encountered?

Comment: If the code does work, then this should be removed from the question and added as an answer instead.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer.

Comment: The code That i posted does not work...
I get "BASIC runtime error.
Sub-procedure or function procedure not defined." Error

I have started reading the documentation you linked for me. but i am only at around page 40